# weird syntax error in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% for item in items %}
   hiii 
{% endfor %)
```

i am using this template and while rendering it i am getting

> In template /home/user/code/templates/temp_name, error at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres a paren at the end of the endfor instead of a curly brace.

```
{% endfor %)
```

should be

```
{% endfor %}
```